# Transform Map using another Map with the help of Guava

Tags: java, guava

I have a two maps and i want to transform first map value using second map.

```
Map<T, Double> firstMap = Maps.newHashMap(with some value...);
Map<T, Double> secondMap = Maps.newHashMap(with some value...);

Map<T, Double> finalMap = Maps.newHashMap();
for(Entry<T, Double> entry : firstMap.entrySet())
{
  finalMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() * secondMap.get(entry.getKey()));
}
```

I want to transform first Map in following manner.

The value of element T in first map should be multiplied with its value in second Map. First map is a subset of first map.

Thanks.

Comment: Please ask a concrete question. Show us your code and tell us what problems you have.

Comment: Please find above the code to explain the problem.

Comment: You still don't tell us what the problem is. What are your inputs, your expected outputs and your actual outputs when running the above code?

Comment: You can put any values in the map. Instead of for loop, i want to find out if i can use guava here.

Comment: You could use [`Maps.transformEntries`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformEntries(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.collect.Maps.EntryTransformer)), but it will not reduce the amount of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Guava:

```
public static final void main(final String... args) {

    final Map<String, Integer> map1 = ImmutableMap.of("key0", 2, "key1", 3);

    final Map<String, Integer> map2 = ImmutableMap.of("key0", 2, "key1", 3, "key2", 3);

    final Map<String, Integer> transformed = Maps.transformEntries(map1,
            new EntryTransformer<String, Integer, Integer>() {

                @Override
                public Integer transformEntry(final String key, final Integer value) {

                    return map2.get(key) * value;
                }
            });

    //result {key0=4, key1=9}
    System.out.println(transformed);
}
```